# Error 401 al enviar email con JavaScript y AJAX

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, formularios, google-apps-script

Estuve buscado métodos para enviar emails sin PHP o lo menos posible por AJAX, y encontré un método en la página de [Formspree](https://formspree.io). Es muy sencillo, pero navegando [encontré esto por GitHub](https://github.com/dwyl/html-form-send-email-via-google-script-without-server) que funciona perfectamente hasta cierto punto.

A la hora de colocar el JavaScript que requiere esta "herramienta", encuentro que no envía los mails. ¿Por qué? Pues solo tengo este error en la consola del navegador:

> POST https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbyhl9S5fO406P61lezf_mmSh5Oq5s_SeZw1a6tMnHIlP3xkgw0/exec 
>   
> handleFormSubmit @ form-submission-handler.js:68
>   
> /web/Adhara/#contacto:1 XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbyhl9S5fO406P61lezf_mmSh5Oq5s_SeZw1a6tMnHIlP3xkgw0/exec. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 401.

Ésta es una aplicación construida con un script de Google que básicamente envía emails a través de GMail que salen de un formulario de contacto común. Cuando se envía el correo con los datos pertinentes, te manda a otra página que contiene un archivo JSON, ellos te ofrecen una solución en formato .js que hace que el archivo JSON trabaje con AJAX y aparezca un mensaje de "Enviado con éxito" al enviarse, por lo que ahora podemos no solo mantenernos en la página sino que podemos estilizarla un poco más.

El problema es que en mi caso, al implementar este .js me salta el anterior error en la consola y nunca se envía el email. Arriba está la documentación para que puedan comprenderla, la app se desarrolla en el vínculo de arriba, y [éste es el .js problemático](https://github.com/dwyl/html-form-send-email-via-google-script-without-server/blob/master/form-submission-handler.js).

Por último, aquí dejo mi html (no adjunto mis CSS ni JS, a menos de ser necesario):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Adhara Arts - Inicio</title>
  <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="./img/adharaico.png">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/main.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Hind|Inconsolata|Pacifico|Roboto|Amatic+SC|Poiret+One" rel="stylesheet">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <!--<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>-->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/typed.js"></script>
  <script src="./js/particles.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/main.js"></script>
  <script src="./js/modernizr.custom.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/masonry-layout@4/dist/masonry.pkgd.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/imagesloaded@4/imagesloaded.pkgd.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/classie/1.0.1/classie.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/AnimOnScroll.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/app.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <nav id="menu-principal">
    <ul>
      <li class="menu-button-1" style="font-weight: 400;"><a href="#inicio">Inicio</a></li>
      <li class="menu-button-2" style="font-weight: 400;">
        <a href="#nosotros">Nosotros</a></li>
      <li class="menu-button-3" style="font-weight: 400;">
        <a href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>
      <li class="menu-button-4" style="font-weight: 600;">
        <a href="#contacto">Contacto</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <div class="logo-fixed">
    <a href="#"><img src="./img/adhara-menu-logo.png" alt=""></a>
  </div>
  <section class="section parallax" id="head">
    <div class="front">
      <a href="#"><img src="./img/adhara.png" alt="Adhara" oncontextmenu="return false" ondragstart="return false"></a>
    </div>
  </section>
  <section class="section" id="inicio">
      <span class="typed"></span>
      <div id="parrafo-uno">
        <p>Hola, estás en Adhara, mira todos los productos de nuestra tienda y sientete libre de contactarnos si quieres saber más de esta movida. <br>
        Observa nuestro portafolio y avisanos si te gusta nuestro trabajo, también puedes seguirnos en nuestas redes sociales para más contenido. <br>
        Y no olvides que compartir el arte es lo más importante aquí! Disfruta.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="social-network">
        <div class="social-contain">
          <div id="Instagram"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="social-contain">
          <div id="Facebook"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="social-contain">
          <div id="Google"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="particles-js"></div>
  </section>
  <section class="section" id="nosotros">
    <div id="bg-A">
      <div id="foto-nos">
        <div id="cover1">
          <h1>A</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="segundo-parrafo">
        <h1>¿Quienes somos?</h1>
        <p>Somos un portafolio y tienda de arte y diseño independente. Nos gusta el arte ¡tanto como a cualquiera!
        y queremos compartir lo que hacemos. Si quieres contactarnos para encargos o ¡porque si! haz un poco de scroll ;).
        Mira a todo nuestro equipo >>AQUÍ<<.
        Y no te pierdas de nada ¡Mira todo lo que hay disponible! ¡y quedate con algo!. <strong>Es una orden.</strong>  </p>
        <p id="cratividad"><br>"La creatividad es permitirte a ti mismo cometer errores. El arte es saber cuáles mantener".<br></p>
        <p>-Scott Adams.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
  <section class="grid-section" id="portfolio">
    <div id="grid-title">
      <h1>Mira nuestro trabajo</h1>
    </div>
     <div class="grid-contain">
      <ul class="grid effect-2" id="grid">
        <li class="grid-sizer"></li>
        <li class="grid-item">
          <a class="img-wrap" href="#">
            <img src="./img/grid-i-1.jpg" alt="">
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="grid-item">
          <a class="img-wrap" href="#">
            <img src="./img/grid-i-2.jpg" alt="">
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="grid-item">
          <a class="img-wrap" href="#">
            <img src="./img/grid-i-3.jpg" alt="">
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="grid-item">
          <a class="img-wrap" href="#">
            <img src="./img/grid-i-4.jpg" alt="">
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="grid-item">
          <a class="img-wrap" href="#">
            <img src="./img/grid-i-5.jpg" alt="">
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="grid-item">
          <a class="img-wrap" href="#">
            <img src="./img/grid-i-6.jpg" alt="">
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="grid-item">
          <a class="img-wrap" href="#">
            <img src="./img/grid-i-7.jpg" alt="">
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="grid-item">
          <a class="img-wrap" href="#">
            <img src="./img/grid-i-8.jpg" alt="">
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="grid-item">
          <a class="img-wrap" href="#">
            <img src="./img/grid-i-9.png" alt="">
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="grid-item">
          <a class="img-wrap" href="#">
            <img src="./img/grid-i-10.jpg" alt="">
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="grid-item">
          <a class="img-wrap" href="#">
            <img src="./img/grid-i-11.jpg" alt="">
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="grid-item">
          <a class="img-wrap" href="#">
            <img src="./img/grid-i-12.jpg" alt="">
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </section>
  <section class="section" id="contacto">
    <div class="bg-con">
      <div class="h1-con">
        <h1>Envianos un saludo</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="contenedor-formulario">
        <form id="gform" action="https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbyhl9S5fO406P61lezf_mmSh5Oq5s_SeZw1a6tMnHIlP3xkgw0/exec" class="formulario" name="Formulario-contacto" method="post">
          <div class="inputs">
            <input class="text" type="text" name="name" id="name" required="Requerido">
            <label class="label label-text" for="name">Nombre</label>
          </div>
          <div class="inputs">
            <input class="text" type="email" name="email" id="email" required="Requerido">
            <label class="label label-text" for="nombre">Correo</label>
   <span id="email-invalid" style="visibility:hidden">Must be a valid email address</span>
          </div>
          <div class="inputs mensaje">
            <textarea id="message" name="message" required="Requerido"></textarea>
            <label class="label label-text" for="message">Mensaje</label>
          </div>
          <div class="inputs">
            <input class="enviar" type="submit" id="btn-submit" value="Enviar">
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
   <div style="display:none;" id="thankyou_message">
    <h2><em>Gracias</em> por contactarnos!
      Estaremos de vuelta contigo pronto!</h2>
  </div>
    </div>
  </section>
  <div class="ante-footer">
    <div id="sn-container">
      <p><a href="#">Instagram</a> | <a href="#">Facebook</a> | <a href="#">Google</a></p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <footer><p>Copyright © Adhara Arts 2017 - Created by <a href="#">DC Arts.</a></p></footer>
  <script data-cfasync="false" type="text/javascript" src="./js/form-submission-handler.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Según el mensaje de error, no se puede realizar la operación desde `localhost` y por eso no se autoriza (error 401 que no 404 como pones en la pregunta). ¿Has probado a subir tu código a un servidor (no localhost) y probar desde ahí?

Comment: Deberías crear un [mcve] en el que incluyas lo mínimo de HTML,JavaScript y CSS e incluir todos los detalles mínimos necesarios para reproducir el problema para facilitar a los demás el reproducir el problema. Por ejemplo, en el HTML quita las imágenes y las "explicaciones" largas, deja sólo "haz clic aqui" o algo así.

Answer (score 1):

Vale, ya que esto podría ser una discusión útil, explicaré como solucionar el problema.

Encontre la solución por mis propios medios y en realidad es bastante sencillo, el problema radica a la hora de desarrollar la aplicación, resulta que dejé la configuración por defecto dela versión de la aplicación, esta configuración solo te permite a ti (dueño de la cuenta Google) como usuario utilizar la misma, por lo que lo único que hice fue hacer otra versión de la aplicación permitiendo a todos los usuarios incluyendo anónimos utilizarla. El problema es que tal vez deberían resaltar las configuraciones necesarias en la documentación de Github. No obstante gracias por responder a la pregunta, y para aclarar alguna duda:

1- El problema va a persistir tanto en local (Apache o node.js) como en un servidor web. Hice pruebas en 000Webhost.

2- No creo que haya algún problema al usar la version del .js en local y de igual manera con el cdn.

Por último solo cabe decir que es una herramienta muy útil y de verdad la recomiendo, se puede usar tanto personal como empresarial (Gmail) y es mucho mas fácil que el problemático PHP para  los principiantes en este mundillo. Y es mucho mas controlable, privado e ilimitado que nuestro amigo [Formspree](https://formspree.io/) que de verdad también es muy útil hasta los 1000 correos al mes. Espero que utilicen este método si les interesa. Gracias.

Comment: Que bueno que has vuelto tan pronto a compartir la solución. Por cosas así es importante hacer el [mcve] ya que al autor le ayuda a discernir mejor cuáles son los detalles importantes y a los lectores que deben hacer para reproducir el problema y luego dar una respuesta acertada en lugar de estar adivinando :)

Answer (score 0):

### El problema

Este error ocurre porque estás haciendo un [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) a un dominio diferente al de tu página (en este caso el dominio de Google Script). Por lo tanto, el navegador lo está bloqueando, ya que normalmente permite solamente  solicitudes en el mismo origen por razones de seguridad.

### Una Solución

- Hacer una solicitud de dominio cruzado CORS.

Aquí tienes un tutorial sobre  [cómo usar CORS](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/)

---

Para más detalles ver en SO en Inglés:

- [“No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource”](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20035319/5587982)
- [Why am I seeing an “origin is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin” error here?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9311585/5587982)
- [XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://www.[website].com/](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35553666/5587982)

Sobre todo la respuesta aceptada del primer enlace y los comentarios.

Answer (score 0):

El problema está en cómo has agregado el JavaScript problemático.

Una solución es reemplaces la llamada a la copia local del código problemático por la línea indicada en el paso 10 de las [instrucciones](https://github.com/dwyl/html-form-send-email-via-google-script-without-server) en GitHub.

```
<script data-cfasync="false" type="text/javascript"
src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/dwyl/html-form-send-email-via-google-script-without-server/master/form-submission-handler.js"></script>
```

A continuación un ejemplo (mínimo verificable y completo) que copia un fragmento del código en la pregunta y reemplaza la línea indicada arriba.

```html
<section class="section" id="contacto">
  <div class="bg-con">
    <div class="h1-con">
      <h1>Envianos un saludo</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="contenedor-formulario">
      <form id="gform" action="https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbyhl9S5fO406P61lezf_mmSh5Oq5s_SeZw1a6tMnHIlP3xkgw0/exec" class="formulario" name="Formulario-contacto" method="post">
        <div class="inputs">
          <input class="text" type="text" name="name" id="name" required="Requerido">
          <label class="label label-text" for="name">Nombre</label>
        </div>
        <div class="inputs">
          <input class="text" type="email" name="email" id="email" required="Requerido">
          <label class="label label-text" for="nombre">Correo</label>
          <span id="email-invalid" style="visibility:hidden">Must be a valid email address</span>
        </div>
        <div class="inputs mensaje">
          <textarea id="message" name="message" required="Requerido"></textarea>
          <label class="label label-text" for="message">Mensaje</label>
        </div>
        <div class="inputs">
          <input class="enviar" type="submit" id="btn-submit" value="Enviar">
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
    <div style="display:none;" id="thankyou_message">
      <h2><em>Gracias</em> por contactarnos! Estaremos de vuelta contigo pronto!</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>

<script data-cfasync="false" type="text/javascript"
src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/dwyl/html-form-send-email-via-google-script-without-server/master/form-submission-handler.js"></script>
```

Comment: Una pregunta, solo es para gmail o correos corporativos tambien?

Comment: Funciona con cuentas de consumidor (dominio gmail.com) y de G-Suite ("corporativos").

Comment: Muchas gracias (y) una ultima consulta se pueden poner 2 correo o solo 1?

Comment: No me queda claro a que te refieres.

Comment: En la parte donde pones la ditreccion del correo? e pueden poner 2 o solo 1?

Comment: Que tal si lo intentas y me cuentas.